# CommandLine arguments are getting skipped and the rest of the main starts running

Tags: c

Basically I'm making connect 4 as an assignment. I'm trying to pass on command line arguments by using the code below. This is only a part of my main, the part that is needed to pass on command line arguments.
I've ran the code obviously and get a segmentation fault which has nothing to do with it (need to fix this myself later).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int fileRead = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-') {

            if (argv[i][1] == 'h') {
                i++;
                height = atoi(argv[i]);

            } else if (argv[i][1] == 'w') {
                i++;
                width = atoi(argv[i]);

            }
            else if (argv[i][1] == 'f') {
                i++;
                read_information(argv[i]);

                fileRead = 1;

            }
        } else
            printf("Invalid args");

    }
```

I've put `printf()` functions to check if the main didn't run at all, but it definitely runs but just skips the command line arguments  part and starts running the rest of the `main()` and giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: The first thing to do is step through your code using a debugger.  That should give you some important clues as to what might be going wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please [edit] your question to fix the indentation (and first line of the code block), and also specify what command-line arguments you're passing.

Comment: It's hard to tell with partial code, but if a command line argument `argv[i]` with `"-h"`, `"-w"`, or `"-f"` is encountered, the next `argv` argument is always accessed.   There is no checking that it exists (i.e. that `i < argc` after incrementing `i` within the `if` statements).   Remember that `argv[argc]` is NULL, and `atoi()` has undefined behaviour if given a NULL pointer.   If `read_information()` assumes it is passed a non-NULL, it will also have undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes I have just tried using the debugger tool, I've looked at the code for a day and checked what was wrong with it , but apparently it was just me forgetting  the - while passing the arguments. Sorry to have bothered you all with this question!!! Thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of trouble with this example.... Let's assume you are given this command line:

```
program -h
```

first of all, when you do `i++;` once detected `-h` option, you don't check if the next argument exists (this will make you to do `atoi(NULL)` which is an error).  Continues to handle the truth of `i < argc` expression???  After you check this, assume the next input:

```
program -h -w
```

It will try to do `atoi("-w");`, giving as result `0`, but no error at all.  You must check first if the argument is numeric (you can do this using `sscanf(3)`, check the man page)

Some people are used also to group parameters, so you could be given:

```
program -hw 320 200
```

as equivalent to:

```
program -h 320 -w 200
```

There's a utility function `getopt(3)` commonly used to parse command line arguments and options.  You could change your code to this example:

```
#include <getopt.h>

...

int opt;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "h:w:v")) != EOF) { /* colon indicates previous param has an argument */
    switch(opt) {
    case 'h': 
        if (sscanf(optarg, "%d", &height) != 1) 
            error("%s must be numeric\n", optarg);
        break;
    case 'w': 
        if (sscanf(optarg, "%d", &width) != 1) 
            error("%s must be numeric\n", optarg);
        break;
    case 'v': flags |= FLAG_VERBOSE; break;
    /* .... add more options as needed */
    }
} /* while */

/* you can adjust parameters so options don't get in the middle */
argc -= optind; argv += optind; /* this is like "shift n" in sh(1) */
```